# Making the ten green bottles song

Tags: python

```
while x > 0:
    print (str( x ) + "green bottles hanging on the wall")
    print (str( x ) + "green bottles hanging on the wall")
    print ("if one green bottle accidently falls")
```

This is my code but it does not work, can some one help me please?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong output?

Comment: `while x > 0` but then `x` never changes so why should the loop ever terminate?

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 10
while x > 0:
    print (str( x ) + "green bottles hanging on the wall")
    print (str( x ) + "green bottles hanging on the wall")
    print ("if one green bottle accidently falls")
    x = x - 1
    print ("there will be " + str ( x ) + "hanging on the wall")
```

Try adding that to your code. The 'While loop' should allow the program to loop the song while x is larger then 0. and the song will do the sum x = x - 1 and print the new 'x' as a variable.

Comment: Also you should add an extra space before "green" and "hanging" words.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` block doesn't terminate due to the condition not failing (or not met if you haven't initialized your x correctly). For this types of usage, I recommend to use `for` loop rather than `while` to make sure that your code will terminate. e.g.

```
for x in range(10,0,-1):
  #your while block here
```

the `range` function will create a list-like object from 10 to 1, counting down. The `for` loop will iterate over all of the elements and terminate when it's done.